# How I should load and adapt pre-trained models to a Self-ONN converted network?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch

Since the Alexon Network has not been trained with Sarina, this is given:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPyRa.png)
Can it be fixed?

My model is like this:
(AlexNet Model)
To avoid using pre-trained values, I commented on " model.load_state_dict(model_zoo.load_url(model_urls['alexnet']), strict=False)". Is this correct?

````
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.utils.model_zoo as model_zoo
from torch.nn import functional as F
from fastonn import SelfONN2d

__all__ = ['AlexNet', 'alexnet']
model_urls = {
    'alexnet': 'https://download.pytorch.org/models/alexnet-owt-4df8aa71.pth',
}

class AlexNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, features):
        super(AlexNet, self).__init__()
        self.features = features
        self.reg_layer = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 128, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        )
        self.density_layer = nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(128, 1, 1), nn.ReLU())

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features(x)
        x = F.upsample_bilinear(x, scale_factor=2)
        x = self.reg_layer(x)
        mu = self.density_layer(x)
        B, C, H, W = mu.size()
        mu_sum = mu.view([B, -1]).sum(1).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2).unsqueeze(3)
        mu_normed = mu / (mu_sum + 1e-6)
        return mu, mu_normed

def make_layers(cfg, batch_norm=False):
    layers = []
    in_channels = 3
    for v in cfg:
        if v == 'M':
            layers += [nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2)]
        
        elif v == 64:
            conv2d = SelfONN2d(in_channels, v, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=2, q=3)
            if batch_norm:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.BatchNorm2d(v), nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            else:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            in_channels = v            
        elif v == 192:
            conv2d = SelfONN2d(in_channels, v, stride=1, kernel_size=5, padding=3, q=3)
            if batch_norm:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.BatchNorm2d(v), nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            else:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            in_channels = v                        
        else:
            conv2d = SelfONN2d(in_channels, v, stride=1, kernel_size=3, padding=1, q=3)                     
            if batch_norm:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.BatchNorm2d(v), nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            else:
                layers += [conv2d, nn.ReLU(inplace=True)]
            in_channels = v
    return nn.Sequential(*layers)

cfg = {
    'E': [64, 'M', 192, 'M', 384, 256, 256]
}

def alexnet():
    """AlexNet model (configuration "E")
        model pre-trained on ImageNet
    """
    model = AlexNet(make_layers(cfg['E']))
#    model.load_state_dict(model_zoo.load_url(model_urls['alexnet']), strict=False)
    return model
`
```
And I tried to use Self-ONN with q=3 and train the model from the beginning, but I got this error:

`File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Github/DM-Count/train.py", line 68, in <module>
trainer.train()
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Github/DM-Count/train_helper.py", line 125, in train
self.train_eopch()
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Github/DM-Count/train_helper.py", line 155, in train_eopch
ot_loss, wd, ot_obj_value = self.ot_loss(outputs_normed, outputs, points)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Github/DM-Count/losses/ot_loss.py", line 50, in forward
P, log = sinkhorn(target_prob, source_prob, dis, self.reg, maxIter=self.num_of_iter_in_ot, log=True)
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Github/DM-Count/losses/bregman_pytorch.py", line 69, in sinkhorn
return sinkhorn_knopp(a, b, C, reg, maxIter=maxIter,
File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Github/DM-Count/losses/bregman_pytorch.py", line 146, in sinkhorn_knopp
assert a.min() >= 0. and b.min() >= 0., 'Elements in a or b less than 0'
AssertionError: Elements in a or b less than 0`

can anyone help me?
````